# Upload de arquivo com ajax ie8

Tags: jquery, upload, internet-explorer-8

Tenho um formulário multipart-fordata onde preciso enviar o arquivo para processamento no C#.

O código abaixo funciona no IE11 e Chrome.

```
var formData= new FormData();
var planilha = document.getElementById("planilha").files[0];

//formData.append("planilha", $("#planilha").file);
formData.append("planilha", planilha);
formData.append("codigoUsuario", $("#txt_ms_codusuario").val());

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", path_ROOT + "LimiteQuanti/EnviarArquivo", true);
xhr.addEventListener("load", function (evt) { UploadComplete(evt); }, false);
xhr.addEventListener("error", function (evt) { UploadFailed(evt); }, false);
xhr.send(formData);
```

Mas não funciona para IE8.

Buscando na web, achei uma alternativa para isso, que é utilizar o plugin jquery.form.js

Mas, ao tentar o executar o código abaixo, recebo a mensagem "Permissão Negada".

```
var obj = { tipo: 'MULT_FORN', codigoUsuario: $("#txt_ms_codusuario").val() };

        $('#files').ajaxForm({
            data: obj,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: path_ROOT + "LimiteQuanti/EnviarArquivoBrowserAntigo",
            success: function (data) {
                NotificarAlerta('OS DADOS DO ARQUIVO FORAM CARREGADOS COM SUCESSO!');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                NotificarErro('OCORREU UM ERRO AO GRAVAR O ARQUIVO.');
            },

            resetForm: true
        }).submit();
```

Não chega nem a chamar a action na controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult EnviarArquivoBrowserAntigo(string tipo, string codigoUsuario)
```

Output do erro no browser:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu problema esta neste trecho de código abaixo. 
Esse input file esta com invisível e no lugar dele aparece um botão e um input text, porque ele esta estilizado. Ao remover esse código do meu script e tentar selecionar o arquivo direto no input file, funciona. Mas se executar esse código, o problema ocorre

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var versao = versaoIE();

    $('.btnSel').on('click', function () {
        $('.arquivo').trigger('click');
    });

    $('.arquivo').on('change', function () {
        var fileName = '';
        if ($(this)[0].files)
            fileName = $(this)[0].files[0].name;
        else
            fileName = $(this)[0].value;
        $('#file').val(fileName);
    });

});
```

Comment: Posta a mensagem de erro do console (F12) completa, "permissão negada" com certeza é apenas parte do erro, informe a linha que disparou isto, dê detalhes.

Comment: Eu não sei porque, mas parece que so funciona se o formulario conter apenas um único campo input file:
<form name="formUpload" id="formUpload" method="post">
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" />
</form>

Comment: Estranho, consegue reproduzir o código em algo como jsfiddle?

Comment: Não consigo fazer o fiddler funcionar com IE, preciso de permissões para configurar o proxy local no IE, se não o fiddler não captura o tráfico para localhost. Mas não tenho privilégios para fazer isso. Existem restrições de rede.

Comment: Esse input file esta com invisível e no lugar dele aparece um botão e um input text, porque ele esta estilizado. Ao remover esse código do meu script e tentar selecionar o arquivo direto no input file, funciona. Mas se executar esse código, o problema ocorre.